# Блокировка диапазона ip-адресов в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Как правильно внести эти примеры айпи адресов в файл .htaccess для последующей их блокировки ?

```
61.125.138.0 - 61.125.138.127

201.79.58.0 - 201.79.59.255
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deny from 61.125.138.0/25

deny from 201.79.58.0/23

В будущем пользуйтесь [IP to CIDR](http://ip2cidr.com/) для решения вопросов блокирования диапазона IP